# How can I move all vowels from a string to a different array

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, c-strings

I am trying to write a function in C that takes 2 parameters (char *string_1, char *string_2), which will move all vowels from string_1 to string_2. I wrote a function to do this, but the output is not what I expected. The contents of string_2 seem to be quite random and sometimes contain non-vowels.

I wrote a while loop to iterate over string_1, with an if statement to check for vowels. Using pointers, I tried set the contents of string_2 + i to the vowel. Then I made the spot where the vowel used to be in string_1 equal to 
' '. I tried several different algorithms, and traced them too, but I'm not sure where the problem is. Also, I am not permitted to use the string library. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_STR_LEN 2048

void moveVowels(char *string_1, char *string_2)
{

 int i;
 i=0;
 while (*(string_1 + i) != '\0')
 {
    if (*(string_1 + i) == 'a' || *(string_1 + i) == 'A' || *(string_1 + 
    i) == 'e' || *(string_1 + i) == 'E' || *(string_1 + i) == 'i' ||
    *(string_1 + i) == 'I' || *(string_1 + i) == 'o' || *(string_1 + i) == 
    'O' || *(string_1 + i) == 'u' || *(string_1 + i) == 'U')
    {
    *(string_2 + i) = *(string_1 + i);
    *(string_1 + i) = ' ';
    }
    i++;
 }
}


int main()
{
 char stringy[MAX_STR_LEN]="but they also had a secret, and their greatest 
 fear";
 char vowels[MAX_STR_LEN];
 printf("%s\n",stringy);
 moveVowels(&stringy[0],&vowels[0]);
 printf("%s\n", stringy);
 printf("%s\n", vowels);

 return 0;

}
```

Expected Output:

```
but they also had a secret, and their greatest fear
b t th y  ls  h d   s cr t,  nd th  r gr  t st f  r
ueaoaaeeaeieaeea
```

Actual Output:

```
but they also had a secret, and their greatest fear
b t th y  ls  h d   s cr t,  nd th  r gr  t st f  r
\u]
```

Comment: Please don't write `*(pointer+index)`. There is a readable shorthand for it: `pointer[index]`.

Comment: You should do  `char vowels[MAX_STR_LEN] = {0};` otherwise you won't have a null terminator

Comment: Also remember that arrays naturally decay to pointer to their first element. So the expression `stringy` is exactly equal to `&stringy[0]`. You use both, as well as the above mentioned explicit pointer arithmetic. Please stick to *one* consistent style. It will make your code easier to read.

Comment: Note that you will need to keep track of *two different indices*, rather than indexing into both arrays with the same index.

Comment: Vowels array at the beginning is initialized to garbage. Say, for the sake of argument that the first element of vowels is the null termination char, then, you write nothing on it because the first char in stringy is not a vowel. For printf your char* is empty. Secondly, if you do not want spaces in Vowels  you want another index, not i.
Three suggestions:
1. Initialize the array to zero, as @Gillespie noted
2. have another index for the vowels that get incremented only for vowels  so you avoid having spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We, beginners, should help each other.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 2048

char * moveVowels( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    size_t n = strlen( s2 );

    for ( char *p = s1; *s2 != '\0'; ++s2 )
    {
        if ( strchr( vowels, tolower( ( unsigned char )*s2 ) ) != NULL )
        {
            s1[n++] = *s2;
            *p++ = ' ';
        }
        else
        {
            *p++ = *s2;
        }
    }

    s1[n] = '\0';

    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[MAX_STR_LEN] =
    {
        "but they also had a secret, and their greatest fear"
    };

    char s2[MAX_STR_LEN];   

    puts( s1 );
    puts( moveVowels( s2, s1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
but they also had a secret, and their greatest fear
b t th y  ls  h d   s cr t,  nd th  r gr  t st f  rueaoaaeeaeieaeea
```

Take into account that the destination character array must have enough space to accomodate vowels in the tail of the source string.

If you want to insert the new line character between the source string and vowels then the function can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 2048

char * moveVowels( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    size_t n = strlen( s2 );

    s1[n++] = '\n';

    for ( char *p = s1; *s2 != '\0'; ++s2 )
    {
        if ( strchr( vowels, tolower( ( unsigned char )*s2 ) ) != NULL )
        {
            s1[n++] = *s2;
            *p++ = ' ';
        }
        else
        {
            *p++ = *s2;
        }
    }

    s1[n] = '\0';

    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[MAX_STR_LEN] =
    {
        "but they also had a secret, and their greatest fear"
    };

    char s2[MAX_STR_LEN];   

    puts( s1 );
    puts( moveVowels( s2, s1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output in this case is

```
but they also had a secret, and their greatest fear
b t th y  ls  h d   s cr t,  nd th  r gr  t st f  r
ueaoaaeeaeieaeea
```

If you are not allowed to use standard C string functions then you can substitute their calls for loops.

For example the declaration

```
size_t n = strlen( s2 );
```

can be substitute for this code snippet

```
size_t n = 0;

while ( s2[n] ) ++n;
```

So what you need is substitute the function `strchr` for a loop by yourself.

Comment: Per the OP, no string functions allowed.  I.E. no `strlen()` and no `strchr()`

Comment: @user3629249 It is his task to substitute the functions for some kind of loops.

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of the offset in the destination string you can either introduce a new variable - or just increment the pointer itself.

#### Option 1

In this case you need a separate variable to keep track of the offset in the destination string. In your `moveVowels()` function, add a new variable

```c
int j = 0;
```

and change

```c
*(string_2 + i) = *(string_1 + i);
```

to

```c
*(string_2 + j++) = *(string_1 + i);
```

At end of `moveVowels()` function, add a NULL terminator to the destination string:

```c
*(string_2 + j) = '\0';
```

#### Option 2

In this case you just increment the pointer every time you add a new vowel:

```c
*(string_2++) = *(string_1 + i);
```

Again, don't forget the null terminator:

```c
*string_2 = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. does not use any of the string functions
3. performs the desired functionality
4. avoids `printf()` as it is very CPU intensive
5. avoids expressions like: `*(string_1 + i)`
6. makes use of the `ctype.h` header file that exposes `toupper()`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 2048

void moveVowels(char *str, char *extractedVowels)
{
    for( size_t j = 0, i = 0; string_1[i]; i++ )
    {
        int temp = toupper( str[i] );
        if (   temp == 'A' 
            || temp == 'E' 
            || temp == 'I' 
            || temp == 'O' 
            || temp == 'U')
        {
            extractedVowels[j] = str[i];
            j++;
            str[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    char stringy[MAX_STR_LEN]="but they also had a secret, and their greatest fear";
    char vowels[MAX_STR_LEN] = {'\0'};

    puts( stringy );

    moveVowels(&stringy[0],&vowels[0]);

    puts( stringy );
    puts( vowels );

    return 0;
}
```

running the proposed code results in:

```
but they also had a secret, and their greatest fear
b t th y  ls  h d   s cr t,  nd th  r gr  t st f  r
ueaoaaeeaeieaeea
```

However, the OPs code (and the proposed code) fail to handle when a trailing 'y' is also a vowel.